# Difficult rate of change question

Tags: calculus

I have no idea how to do this one. I know I need to set up rates and stuff, but I don't even know where to begin.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you should use is:

$$x^2 + 4.5^2 = (L - 6+h)^2$$

and that's the equation you should differentiate implicitly wrt $t$ (time).

Remember that the total length of the rope $L$ is a constant, as is the vertical "drop" of the tractor relative to the pulley ($4.5m$). Everything else is variable. The length of the rope between tractor and pulley is given by $L-(6-h)$ and that's how you end up with the above equation using Pythagoras' Theorem.

Differentiating implicitly wrt $t$,

$$2x\frac{dx}{dt} = 2(L-6+h)(\frac{dh}{dt})$$

and I trust you're able to proceed from there.

One more clue: you're not given $L$ or $h$ explicitly, but you can determine $L - 6 + h = L - (6-h)$ at the "end point" (when tractor is $5m$ away from bale) by using Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: I see where you are going; however, instead of (L-h+6)^2, wouldn't it be (L-(6-h)) or (L-6+h), because you would want to subtract h-6 from the length of the rope L?

Comment: @Chris You're right, made a mistake with the algebra. Fixed now. Note that this means the negative sign on the derivative on the RHS is also dropped.

Comment: @Chris Did my answer help you? If so, it's proper form to accept it. That will also make others more likely to help in future. :)

Comment: Yes it did :) Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Chris You're most welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

L=sqrt(x^2+4.5^2)+6-h is an appropriate equation

dh/dt = dh/dL x dx/dt x dL/dx

dx/dt = 3  (given)

dh/dL = -1

dL/dx = x/sqrt(x^2+4.5^2)

when x=5

dL/dx = 0.743 (to 3 sig figs)

therefore dh/dt= -1x3x0.743

dh/dt=-2.23m/sec

Comment: Try using proper formatting for your posts here.